# Ionic App for Android alternative way to update

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing an application for android with ionic, it will be an app which will not get to Play Store, I will generate the apk and my client will install it on his devices.

My first question is: I will use SQLite to store some informations, will these informations be lost if I need to update the app through generation of new apk and install it manually?

Second: There is another way to update the app remotely? Since it won't be on Play Store, how can I make the app update himself since I don't want to use any third party service for this?

Answer (score 0):

*I will use SQLite to store some informations, will these informations be lost if I need to update the app through generation of new apk and install it manually*

Any data stored in database is kept between app updates.
You can alter (delete rows by example) this data in your new version if you want using the SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade() method ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)))

*Second: There is another way to update the app remotely? Since it won't be on Play Store, how can I make the app update himself since I don't want to use any third party service for this?*

There are some good services for this but I recommend to check [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/).

Comment: its important to note that all updates will be delivered as a new apk to be installed on devices, even so those informations will be kept?

Comment: Yes.. when you install a new apk (make sure you sign it correctly and always with the same key) the Package Manager will ask the user to update the app if it already exists on his device.